# Programatically changing post's permalink when identical post type is published

Tags: permalinks, archives

Is there a way in Wordpress for me to create content for a specific permalink ( mysite.com/current-issue ) that can be updated each month. With each update, the old content's permalink is automatically shifted to a new permalink, mysite.com/previous-issues// ?

At this point, I'm not asking for detailed "how to," just a general approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By default, WordPress will present the posts in order of newest to oldest so that part is already covered unless you've changed that behavior with a custom query.

In order to do this, you will need to create a new rewrite rule using the [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) function that points `/current-issue/` to the first post of that category/post type/taxonomy/etc that you are using to designate these posts. The resulting page should show only 1 post and have no reference to `wp_link_pages()` in the template file/part.

As for creating `/previous-issues/`, it will be the same principal but you'll need a custom query with an offset of `1` in order to skip the first post.

Edit: One thing I forgot to add - after you add these rule you will need to flush the rewrite rules. This can be done simply by going to **Settings -> Permalinks** and simply saving them without making changes.